# Telegram accounts get banned when using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

After the start of the bans of accounts connected to my project, I changed the system for receiving new messages in the telegram account. Previously, I implemented it through a handler, now it is possible to connect several accounts, performing actions with unread messages on each one in turn. Code:

```
async def start_wtf_blyat():
global client, current_session_account
while True:
    for cl in clients:
        current_session_account = cl[0]
        client = cl[1]
        print(f'Choosing {current_session_account.session_name}')

        if current_session_account.start_time is not None:
            if current_session_account.start_time > dt.datetime.utcnow():
                print(
                    f"{current_session_account.session_name}: {current_session_account.start_time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')} > {dt.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')}")
                s_d = (current_session_account.start_time - dt.datetime.utcnow().replace(
                    microsecond=0)) * random.randrange(
                    1, 3)
                print(f'{current_session_account.session_name} needs to sleep {s_d.seconds} seconds')
                await asyncio.sleep(s_d.seconds)
                print(f'{current_session_account.session_name}: Sleep complete!')
        current_session_account.start_time = dt.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)

        current_session_account.activate()

        async with client:
            print(f'Starting {current_session_account.session_name}')
            await check_news()

        print(
            f'{current_session_account.session_name}: Work complete! END: {current_session_account.end_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}')
```

Then the necessary messages are selected in the check_news():

```
async def check_news():
global current_session_account, ME
ME = await client.get_me()

await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5, 1))
# try:
x = [[d.unread_count, d.entity.id, d.title] for d in await client.get_dialogs() if
     not getattr(d.entity, 'is_private', False) and type(d.entity) == Channel
     and d.unread_count != 0 and d.entity.id in INPUT_CHANNELS_IDS]

if not x:
    rnd_sleep = random.randrange(180, 300)
    print(f'{current_session_account.session_name}: No channels, sleep for {rnd_sleep} seconds')

    end_time = dt.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)

    start_time = current_session_account.start_time

    if start_time is not None:
        if start_time < end_time:
            delta = end_time - start_time + dt.timedelta(seconds=rnd_sleep)
    else:
        delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=rnd_sleep)

    print(f'{current_session_account.session_name} START: {start_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}, '
          f'END: {end_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}, '
          f'DELTA: {delta}, '
          f'NEXT START {(end_time + delta).strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}')

    current_session_account.set_times(delta)
    current_session_account.deactivate()
    return

for da in x:
    print(f'{current_session_account.session_name}: {x.index(da) + 1} of {len(x)}')

    await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5, 1))

    async for msg in client.iter_messages(da[1], limit=da[0]):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(3, 5, 1))
        await msg.mark_read()

        if msg.text is None:
            continue

        comm_result_true = await Magic.detect_commercial(msg.text)
        antiplagiat_result = await antiplagiat(msg)

        if not comm_result_true and antiplagiat_result:
            await send_this_post(msg, da[1])
        else:
            print(f'{current_session_account.session_name}: Commercial or plagiat!')

# finally:

end_time = dt.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)

start_time = current_session_account.start_time

if start_time is not None:
    if start_time < end_time:
        delta = end_time - start_time + dt.timedelta(seconds=1)
else:
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=2)

print(f'{current_session_account.session_name} START: {start_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}, '
      f'END: {end_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}, '
      f'DELTA: {delta}, '
      f'NEXT START {(end_time + delta).strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")}')

current_session_account.set_times(delta)
current_session_account.deactivate()

return
```

Finally, the message is processed, the media is downloaded, if any, the text is saved. And other actions are no longer related to the telegram api.

```
async def send_this_post(msg, result):
chan = db.get_input_channel(result)
if db.using_ai(chan[1]):
    check = await Magic.detect_theme(msg.text)
    if check:
        msg_category = CAT_DEF[f'{check}']
    else:
        return
else:
    msg_category = db.get_category_by_input_channel_name(chan[1])

print(f'Theme - {msg_category}')

test = await MSG(msg_cat=msg_category, txt=msg.text, title=chan[2], username=chan[1], datetime=msg.date)
await test.create_media(msg)
await test.create_voice()
await test.create_translates()

await send_to_users_test(test)
return
```

Everything starts as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.warning('IZVESTNIK STARTED.')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    bot.start(bot_token=settings.bot_TOKEN)
    logging.warning(f'BOT {settings.bot_username} just launched.')

    loop.create_task(usr_periods_activity())
    loop.create_task(usr_msg_queue_activity())
    loop.create_task(start_wtf_blyat())
    bot.loop.run_forever()
```

In fact, all that each account does is receive unread messages, download media, mark them as read, but even the launch of 8 accounts resulted in the ban of each of them for 3 days, either in general without an error, or with an **Account deactivated/deleted error (Caused get_dialogs request)**.

Although many users of the telegram application do many times more actions. Recently rereading the documentation, I came across this:
[Text from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ2VN.jpg).
Perhaps the reason is that I am from Russia, and I use Russian SIM cards to register accounts, but a friend from England bought SIM cards for me there several times, but they also received a ban. The project release is located on the WDM server, the ip is also Russian, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: You are violating the terms of service of the platform and you are asking for help to bypass that?

Comment: I have read everything related to the terms of use, none of them violates my project, if you have information about what exactly the presented code violates, please share

Comment: you were banned for a reason and you are trying to evade and get around the ban.

Comment: Nope, I just whant to know the reason to edit the base logic of my project to no longer violate ToS...

Comment: That's not the same, because the idea of my project does not violate anything, the problem is in the implementation, and that's what I need help with.

Comment: ask telegram's admin why you banned and then you will know what you have to change in project.

Comment: It doesn't look like your code is indented correctly; could you double-check this, and make edits as necessary?

Comment: @furas, so far, the administrators are not responding, so I decided to ask a question here, maybe there is a solution to the problem from the technical side.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, of course, I'll do it today, as soon as I can get to the computer. I note that the whole project is more than 3000 lines, this is only a small part of the code in which there is a problem somewhere, so you will not be able to fully run it

Comment: I found the solution. Just accounts from another country and proxy...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution of this issue is just write an "impulse" activity script against pooling script. Also use SIM cards from another country for telegram accounts and proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend to use different version

pip install Telethon==1.1

this version can't ban your account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).